# classLoader.getResource() works in Eclipse but returns null when deployed

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, nullpointerexception, resources

I have an issue when I create a executable jar for my application where I'm unable to read any file located in the resource folder.
The resource files are located under : src > main > resources.

I have a .xml config file and the log4j.properties file there.

When I run the application from within Eclipse everything works fine ( xml is read out and log file is created) but when I deploy it as an executable jar then suddenly no log file is written anymore and classLoader.getResource( xmlFile) returns null.

Any idea how to solve this?

This is piece of code I use:
The parameter xmlFile is just the filename such as  'readMe.xml'

```
private Document xmlDocument (String xmlFile) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    // return null if the file is not an xml file
    System.out.println(" - xmlFile  : " + xmlFile);
    if(! xmlFile.substring(xmlFile.lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase().equals("xml")  ){
        return null;
    }

    //Get Document Builder
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

    //Build Document
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();

    URL res = classLoader.getResource( xmlFile);
    System.out.println(" - res : " + res);

    File file = new File( classLoader.getResource(  xmlFile).getFile() );
    if (file == null){
        System.out.println(" - xmlDocument - OUT");
        return null;
    }

    Document document = builder.parse(new File(classLoader.getResource(xmlFile).getFile()));
    //Normalise the XML Structure; 
    System.out.println(" - xmlDocument 5 - before normalizing document");
    document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    return document;
}
```

Comment: Is everything now in a jar? Objects in a jar are not files and you can't use `File` to access them. Look at `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Did you check that your .jar file contains a `readMe.xml` entry?  You can examine a .jar file’s contents in your IDE, or you can use the `jar` tool that comes with every JDK, or you can make a copy of it and change the copy’s extension to `.zip` and then use any zip tool to examine the file (since every .jar file is in fact a zip file). Be aware that URL.getFile() **does not** convert a URL to a valid file name.  Do not attempt to convert your URL to a File at all.  Use `try (InputStream file = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(xmlFile)) { document = builder.parse(file); }` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to specify the resources in classpath, try this.

1. Export your classes as normal jar, not executable jar.
2. Copy all your resources to a config directory say `<base_paths>/config` and jars to a directory say `<base_paths>/lib`.
3. Run command

in windows

```
java -cp <base_paths>/config;<base_paths>/lib/yourJar.jar com.xyz.YourMainclass
```

in Unix

```
java -cp <base_paths>/config:<base_paths>/lib/yourJar.jar com.xyz.YourMainclass
```